# Why can't I load this json file in python?

Tags: python, json, character-encoding

Solution, if someone finds this when googling it:
The problem was not with the code per se, but with the download on Firefox. Apparently (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1470011) some servers will gzip files twice. The downloaded file should then be called file.json.gz.gz, but has one .gz missing. It needs to be extracted twice to get to the content.

---

I am trying to sort through some information in this file: https://dl.vndb.org/dump/vndb-tags-latest.json.gz
I am also very new to working with json, but I can't find anything that helps me.

The problem is that I can't get it to load it into python. Extracting the .gz file with 7zip and trying to load the file with `json.load(open('vndb-tags-2020-12-31.json', encoding='utf-8'))` returns the error

`>>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`.

Without the utf-8 argument I get

`>>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: illegal multibyte sequence`

instead. I run into the same problem when I try to decrypt the file on the go using the gzip package

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('vndb-tags-2020-12-31.json.gz') as fd:
    json.load(fd)
>>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I am guess that I need a different encoding option, but utf-16 and 32 don't work and I can't find anything on the help page https://vndb.org/d14

Comment: Try a different encoding such as latin-1

Comment: The .json file is the content of the .gz archive, if that's what you mean. It gives me the error

Comment: I can load it with your code just fine btw

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Latin-1 also gives `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I also can't find a complete list of encoding options to try, could you point me to one?

Comment: @Chris No, 3.7.4 . Are there any other dependencies I'm maybe not aware of?

Comment: Odd. Downloaded your file then extracted using 7zip and latin-1 worked on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download, extract and load your data as json blow-by-blow;

1. Send request to target url and catch the data as byte-object
2. Load and reserve its data on memory cell with io module.
3. Pass the io-object to gzip function and extract it to json data
4. Pass the json string to dump property and reserve it as a python dictionary

**Try this:**

```
import requests, io, gzip, json


url = 'https://dl.vndb.org/dump/vndb-tags-latest.json.gz'
file_object = io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)

with gzip.open(file_object, 'r') as gzip_file:
    reserve_data = gzip_file.read()

load_json = json.loads(reserve_data)
beautiful_json = json.dumps(load_json, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print(beautiful_json)
```

For larger files its better to save your gzip on disk, then load it from disk:

```
import requests, gzip, json

target_url = 'https://dl.vndb.org/dump/vndb-tags-latest.json.gz'
downloaded_gzip_file = requests.get(target_url).content

with open("my_json_file.gz", "wb") as gz_file:
    gz_file.write(downloaded_gzip_file)

with gzip.open("my_json_file.gz") as gz_file:
    load_json_data = json.load(gz_file)

beautiful_json = json.dumps(load_json_data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print(beautiful_json)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I don't really understand the difference. I thought that downloading the file manually and loading it into python worked the way I did it, but that appears to be where the problem is, since I can't read the gzip_file. Any clue as to what the difference is between your code and `with gzip.open(filepath, 'r') as gzip_filo: data = gzip_filo.read()`

Comment: @kan-don did you check your target file checksum with its original signature (i mean its hash)? sometimes when you download your files manually they can be corrupted/unreadable and so gzip cannot parse them.

Comment: @kan-don if you wanna download your gzip file and save it on your disk then read and parse it from disk instead of reserving its bytes on memory i can update my answer with this situation.

Comment: Yes, that would be very helpful. I'm not sure how to checksum, but I've downloaded the file 3 separate times thinking that maybe it was corrupted, but I guess that would make the error appear during the gzip.open part anyway.

Comment: @kan-don; check my updates; its ok on my system.

Comment: @kan-don; the sha256 hash of file on my system is f597df564af2bae5a25f7a4d3e1d0370c71e6d2fbbbf82f3b4a2ef49fd8c3179, whats your os ? if you are on linux just type sha256sum file_name.gz in terminal; it will give you sha256; check your sha256 with mine; you downloaded your file correclty if your hash is equal to mine. (sha256 is one of the checksum algorithms, we have many other algorithms)

Comment: I'm on Win10, so if I did this correctly via `certUtil -hashfile` it's 1d50fda17f9d41097503b8c6154304b3b2ff14f6c3c843d7cf106546abed12c1, which is not the same. Downloading the file with your updated code however gives me your checksum. I tried downloading the file with Chrome instead of Firefox and it also gives me the 'correct' checksum, then again with Firefox and I get the wrong one. I also noticed Chrome puts the '(1)' before .json and FF before .gz when the file already exists, not sure if that's just renaming convention or if it's related to the problem, but it's kinda weird.

Comment: Ok so I solved the issue: I had to unpack the .json file **again**. Apparently this is an issue with FF, I found [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1470011) regarding tar.gz files. I don't know much about this stuff, but I noticed the filesize of the extracted .json file was the exact same as the .gz downloaded via Chrome/script (edit: SHA256 match too). Anyway, thank you very much, I really appreciate you taking the time to help!

Comment: @kan-don; yw :) check this link about hash if the filename changes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220017/does-the-hash-of-a-file-change-if-the-filename-changes; and remember that one of the methods used by many A.V (anti-virus apps) is checksum; malware can change their names but A.V can still detect them with their checksums.